# Is RCurl currently broken on Windows? (error:1407742E:SSL)

Tags: r, windows, ssl, rcurl

Good day one and all.
I have been using RCurl to load https://raw. tables from our GitHub repository for data cleanup and analysis. Recently (maybe two weeks) every script using:

```
read.csv(text = getURL())
```

stopped working, throwing an error as such:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

Unfortunately my understanding of SSL and related issues is very limited (I still git using login credentials in bash).
The thing is, on my Debian machine at work, the code executes flawlessly. And upon removing geURL() and sticking to simple read.csv(), even the Windows code works.
Which is fine but I have functions dependent on url.exists() which also get broken and I have been unable to find a replacement for that.

```
    version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.3                         
year           2020                        
month          10                          
day            10                          
svn rev        79318                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
nickname       Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out
```

Thank you in advance for anything that might get me closer to a solution.

Comment: Some time ago, GitHub dropped support for TLS versions before 1.2, it seems possible that this could be contributing to your problem here. Since it's windows, perhaps your install of windows is lacking the updated libraries. You might try pre-downloading with `FN <- tempfile(); download.file(getURL(), FN, method="libcurl")` to see if that produces different results.

Comment: hi. firstly, thank you for the quick answer. secondly, I rand the command in R and it does produce a result of: 
```Error in getURL() : argument "url" is missing, with no default```

Comment: I used your sample code as a template. Replace `getURL()` in my code with whatever URL you are trying to use.

Comment: I see. Re-run it and I get exactly the same error as on the described problem.

Comment: Okay, sorry, it was a thought.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/5806. If the issue is correct, then your openssl libraries (somewhere on your system) are 2+ years out of date. (I don't know offhand how to fix it.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the RCurl package for Windows is linked to a very old version of curl (7.40). For reasons I do not know, even the most current packages of RCurl still link to that old version.

In order to use a recent version of curl, you have to install RCurl from the source by using https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ .

For compiling RCurl you need to install curl with the relevant header files using "Rtools bash" by the following commands:

```
pacman -Sy

pacman -S mingw-w64-{i686,x86_64}-curl
```

After that, you can install RCurl from the source:

```
install.packages("RCurl", type="source)
```