# R blocks an URL?

Tags: r

On my Linux machine I have been working on a package which provides a R-client to BaseX.
On that machine all tests are passed.
When executing the same code on Windows however, one test fails. `url.exists("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BaseXdb/basex/master/basex-api/src/test/resources/first.xml")` returns FALSE.
I checked with some other URL's.
`url.exists("https://www.cnn.com")` is accepted. `url.exists("https://nos.nl")` is rejected.

Why are all the URL's accepted by Linux? And why are **some** blocked by Windows? All machines are in the same home-network.

Ben

Comment: try something like `spsUtil::checkUrl("https://nos.nl")`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to RCurl using an old version of curl rather than the url being blocked by windows (I get the same error even with the most updated version of RCurl). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65887594/is-rcurl-currently-broken-on-windows-error1407742essl) for details.

In the meantime, there are lots of other solutions. For example, the `httr` package is very useful (`httr::GET(url)` will work here), and even R's built-in tools should be able to negotiate with GitHub - try `readLines`

```r
readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BaseXdb/basex/master/basex-api/src/test/resources/first.xml")
#> [1] "<first><title>First Document</title></first>"
```